# Treeview removing highlight when using an update loop

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a `Treeview` table that calls records from an external MongoDB collection, which changes frequently, so I need to use an update loop to reflect the changes in my table. Whenever I highlight a row with the cursor, it displays the highlighted row with the selected background colour.

The problem is when the loop updates, the highlight disappears. I was wondering if someone could show me a method for keeping the highlight in place, regardless of the table updates?

If you run this code, you'll see what I mean:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import ttk as TTK


root  = Tk()
style = TTK.Style()
tv    = TTK.Treeview()

def highlight_row(event):

    tree = event.widget
    item = tree.identify_row(event.y)
        
    tree.tk.call(tree, "tag", "remove", "highlight")
    tree.tk.call(tree, "tag", "add", "highlight", item)

tv.grid(row=1, column=0)
tv.tag_configure('highlight', background='orange')
tv.bind("<Motion>", highlight_row)


style.configure("Treeview", font=(None, 12))
style.configure("Treeview", foreground= '#3F3F3F',
                            background= '#3F3F3F',
                            fieldbackground='#3F3F3F')


tv['columns'] = ('a','b','c')

tv.heading('a', text='a')
tv.column('a', anchor='center', width=100)
tv.heading('b', text='b')
tv.column('b', anchor='center', width=175)
tv.heading('c', text='c')
tv.column( 'c', anchor='center', width=90)


external_db = [{'x':1,'y':2, 'z':3},
               {'x':4,'y':5, 'z':6},
               {'x':7,'y':8, 'z':9}]
                                            
def update():

    try:

        for j in tv.get_children():
            tv.delete(j)

        for j, k in enumerate(external_db):
            
            tv.insert('', 'end', text=str(j), values=(k['x'],k['y'],k['z']) ,tags = ('col'))
            tv.tag_configure('col', foreground = 'white')

    except Exception, e:
        print e, 'Update Exception'
        pass
    
    root.after(1500,update)


update()
root.mainloop()
```

i.e. there is an orange background highlight that disappears every time `root.after(1500,update)` is called.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

#_____________________
Here is what `root.configure(background="#3F3F3F")` does for me:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply remembering the selection and reapplying it? Or, just delete the items that have been removed rather than deleting everything.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley You mean pickle the item location, and then call it inside the loop and apply it to `highlight_row`?

Comment: @BryanOakley, the item identifier changes on every iteration. So no point in storing it.

Comment: You can use your own identifiers, or create mappings. Presumably  your database gives each item a unique id, which you can use when creating the items in the treeview.

Comment: No, I don't mean to pickle the item location. Just get the list of selected items, then iterate over the list to restore the selection.

Comment: @BryanOakley, worked a charm, thanks. Have you any idea how to fill space at the bottom of Treeview (without creating blank dummy rows)?

Comment: Why do you need to fill space at the bottom? I don't quite understand what you're asking. What do you want the space to be filled with?

Comment: @BryanOakley, the background colour of my Treeview rows is grey. When there are only a few entries in my Treeview, the rest of the application is white space (i.e. the rest of the table without any data is white, I would prefer if it was grey). So I am filling out the remainder n-x rows with blank strings, and then colouring them grey. Purely cosmetic, it's niggling me. In short, if my application window size is equivalent to 50 rows, and my table data is 20 rows, I am creating 30 rows of blank strings and colouring them grey. Has to be a better way.

Comment: Why don't you just change the color of the background to match?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have already tried that in the example above, but it still comes out white. I have `foreground`, `background` and `fieldbackground` all set to '#3F3F3F', but it only covers the amount of data in the table, not the white space.

Comment: I don't see where you've tried it. When I set the background of the window as a whole, it works for me.

Comment: @BryanOakley, do you use the `style.configure` option, or do it directly? How? sorry for nagging you.

Comment: In your code it's as simple as `root.configure(background="#3F3F3F")`

Comment: @BryanOakley, that colours the canvas, not the remaining rows, see above. I think it's just a limitation of the API.

Comment: On my machine I get a solid dark-gray window, even in the bottom part of the tree. You appear to be using python 2.x which is no longer supported. I recommend you upgrade to python3. There might have been some improvements in tkinter. Please don't ask about two separate questions. If you need more help, ask a separate question.

Comment: @BryanOakley, trust me, I want to use python 3, but i have written so much in 2.7 that it would scare me to change at this point.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thanks for the hand anyhow. All the best.

Comment: @BryanOakley, solved it -  I set `style.theme_use("clam")` and that worked... don't ask why. Found the solution in the nether-regions of some website. Nightmare.